# How to enable two factor authentication in Office 365?

Tags: office-365, multi-factor-auth

The two factor authentication option cannot be found when the settings button has been clicked.

Comment: This question is not about using a web application as end-user.

Comment: @Rubén On which stackexchange site would this Q&A on topic?

Comment: Please ask on [meta.se]

Comment: Regarding where to ask, I think that this could help [Which Stack Exchange site is best for Microsoft Exchange questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252900/289691)

Comment: @Rubén Could you move this Q&A to serverfault or should I delete this one and create it on serverfault?

Comment: I can't. You could flag it for moderator attention or try to delete  and repost it. I think that you should delete the answer first.

Comment: You are welcome to re-ask the question there if you believe it's within their scope, but I'm not 100% confident that's where it actually belongs.  Are you trying to set up 2-FA for an individual account or for a whole group of people?  If it's the former, it's probably okay remaining here.

Comment: This isn't Exchange - its office 365 tho.

Comment: This seems on-topic to me.

Comment: @ale Do you mean that managing/configuring web applications for organization users by an administrator is on topic on this site?

Comment: @pnuts, yes I'm sure. The OP  published an answer less than an hour after they published the question. The answer refers to an article for administrators, and the steps mentioned require to be an administrator to apply them.

Comment: @pnuts: I'm an Office 365 for education user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69977/discussion-between-ruben-and-pnuts).

Answer (score 2):

[This article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-up-multi-factor-authentication-for-Office-365-users-8f0454b2-f51a-4d9c-bcde-2c48e41621c6) explains how to enable two factor authentication. It contains a link to [the Office Admin Center](https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home). When the link was clicked the Admin Center opened.

Users > Active users > select user > Manage multi-factor authentication > select user > enable

When the user logs is, he/she has to enter his/her phonenumber, choose between receive a text message or phone call. Once the phone number has been entered, a text message could be received, the number be entered and login to office.com.

**Note:** it seems that two-factor authentication is multi-factor authentication in office